# Incorrect Syntax near "*"

Tags: c#, sql-server, syntax

I'm having problems with my code. I haven't used SQL services at anytime, so its kinda tricky to figure out what's the problem. The main problem is what it says on the title, i get incorrect Syntax when i try to `Read`, `Update` or `Delete` data from `SQL database`.

Here is the code:

```
string Connection2 = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\AuthMyRegistery\AuthMyRegistery\Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
string Query = "delete from * where idWorkerInfo='" + this.WorkerIdTextBox.Text + "';";
SqlConnection Conn2 = new SqlConnection(Connection2);
SqlCommand Command2 = new SqlCommand(Query, Conn2);
SqlDataReader Reader2;
Conn2.Open();
Reader2 = Command2.ExecuteReader();
MessageBox.Show("Data Deleted");
while (Reader2.Read())
{
}
Conn2.Close();
```

Comment: Where do you get that error? What is in `this.WorkerIdTextBox.Text`? Even heard of parameterized queries?

Comment: Perhaps you need to re-read the syntax required for a DELETE statement

Comment: you should never put the content of a TextBox directly into a sql string. google sql injection...

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 6):

Issue is here, no table name defined

```
delete from * where idWorkerInfo=
```

Should be

```
Delete From TableName where idWorkerInfo=
```

Answer (score 4):

'*' isn't a valid target for a delete statement, what table do you want to delete from?

The syntax should be something like

```
delete from MyTable where idWorkerInfo='abc'
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the name of table instead of a wildcard.

The basic syntax of the DELETE statement is the following (see the full documentation in MSDN - [DELETE (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx)):

```sql
DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE some_column=some_value;
```

Moreover, you should not be creating your SQL query using string concatenation (**never** ever use this in production), as this makes you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Instead, you should be using a parameterized query so that all user input gets properly escaped:

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE idWorkerInfo=@id", conn2);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", WorkerIdTextBox.Text);  
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no `*` in `delete` ... The syntax of delete is as follows

```
DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE some_column = some_value;
```

Answer (score 2):

The query itself is incorrect.

Consider this:

```
delete from * where idWorkerInfo='Sth'
```

You need to replace * with an actual table name.